# How do i replace hard coded values in LINQ query by a C# list

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How do i replace the hard coded array new int[] {102,7,39} by values from the List called ListOfAuditors in this query ?

```
public IList<UserDetails> GetAllAssociatesForGivenListOfAuditors(IList<UserDetails> ListOfAuditors)
        {
            using (OPMSDataSourceDataContext db = new OPMSDataSourceDataContext())
            {
                var query = (from AuditorAssociatemaps in db.AuditorAssociatemaps
                             where
                               (new int[] { 102, 7, 39 }).Contains(AuditorAssociatemaps.AuditorID)
                             group new { AuditorAssociatemaps.UserData, AuditorAssociatemaps } by new
                             {
                                 AuditorAssociatemaps.UserData.FirstName,
                                 AuditorAssociatemaps.AssociateID
                             } into g
                             orderby
                               g.Key.FirstName
                             select new UserDetails
                             {
                                 FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                                 UserID = g.Key.AssociateID
                             }).ToList();
                return query;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can find the item in a list [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281311/find-item-in-ilist-with-linq

Comment: Like you would literally, you select the text `new int[] { 102, 7, 39 }` and paste the text `ListOfAuditors` over it.

Comment: You can find the item in a list [here][1]


Also, pertinent [this example][2]



  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869908/how-to-use-ilist-contains-method-to-find-an-object

Comment: There is no way you wrote this and you are asking this question. Please ask the original author of the code, modifying other peoples code by using copy&paste from the internet is not getting you anywhere. Learn to write code yourself.

Comment: I am doing what you said @BenjaminGruenbaum. I am almost there i think.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
...    
var ids = ListOfAuditors.Select(a => a.Id)
...
```

and, in the query:

```
where ids.Contains(AuditorAssociatemaps.AuditorID)
```